# SharePoint 2010 on showing local Image in IMG tag

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have a SharePoint 2010 intranet that shows images from a unc path.  I use an img tag like the following:

`<img width="50px" height="25px" src="file://ShareName/Folder/image.jpg">`

The problem is that it works fine in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox.  I did some googling and it said try using `file://///` in place of `file://`.  This doesn't work either.  It makes me believe it's a security issue of some type. Chrome/Firefox don't allow local files to show?

Has anyone run into this before? If so, how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using UNC path?

You can use layouts or hive folder of SharePoint instead, just copy your images/CSS/JS stuff in a separate folder here:

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`

and than refer to the files in your solution as, for example:

`<img width="50px" height="25px" src="/_layouts/folderName/imageFile.jpg">`

**CAN'T PUT FILES TO LAYOUTS FOLDER**

In this case, you should put your files in a document library (most commonly Style Library / Style Assets).. And reference the files using relative URLs like:

`/Style Library/ImagesFolder/logo.jpg`

If you are using Publishing Template, you have Images library (Publishing Image Library).. You can put your files in that library.

References:

[How to use relative URL for image in Master Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65051/how-to-use-relative-url-for-image-in-master-page)

Comment: Thank you Arsalan.  You got me going on the right track.  This  folder is maintained by another dept so copying it the the layouts folder was not an option.
<br />
Since it's an internal intranet, I choose to make a virtual directory(VD) from the site in IIS.  The VD has the UNC location as it's path.  This way I was able to use a link such as /FolderName/ImageFile.jpg.

Comment: Please check the update..