# Adding relative image in master page

Tags: master-page

I've been struggling with this for some time now. I need to add a relative path from top site: Currently I've tried at least 2 options but in each case the code gets appended by SPD with __designer:Preview ect. I found a blog but cant see how to rewrite :
[blog on issue](http://vyeung.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/sharepoint-designer-2010-addinggenerating-__designer-preview-tags-a-fix-to-solve-this-issue/)
I need to go to site collection level as I'm adding master page to sub-templates.
Any help appreciated, I also think $SPUrl causing issues with templates.

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Images/logo1.png %>" runat="server"/>

<img src="<asp:literal runat='server' Text='<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Images/logo1.png%>'></asp:literal>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<img src="/Style Library/Images/logo.jpg" />
```

See this for more info:
[How to use relative URL for image in Master Page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65051/how-to-use-relative-url-for-image-in-master-page)

Comment: That works but when I create sub-site from template the path is wrong. as now I need to reference the site collection. This is why I'm trying to reference site collection independently.