# Double replacement for site collection replacement token in master page?

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, url

I am setting up custom branding for a site, using a custom master page, and linking to custom css, image and script files all hosted in the `Style Library` on the root web of the site collection.

[As suggested in this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/65062/8992), I am using the replacement token `../..` to refer to the site collection.  So, for example, some of my links look like this:

```
<link href="../../Style Library/custom/css/custom_v2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<asp:Image ImageUrl="../../Style Library/custom/img/logo3.png" runat="server" />
```

This works fine for the home page of the site, and for any main list view for any of the lists or libraries on the site.  However, if I go to a "system" page, like `Site Contents` or `Site Settings`, everything gets broken, and I can see that my links have turned into this:

```
<link href="../../sites/mysite/Style Library/custom/css/custom_v2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<asp:Image ImageUrl="../../sites/mysite/Style Library/custom/img/logo3.png" runat="server" />
```

So it seems as though the URL replacement is happening twice in those cases.  Why is this happening, and is there anything I can do about it?

(The same custom master page is specified for both `SPWeb.MasterUrl` and `SPWeb.CustomMasterUrl`.)

Comment: Is your site publishing enabled? Then you can use `SPUrl` token instead of `..`

Comment: Yes it is, and I just found this other answer over on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3898034/988264 , which I am trying out right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Ok, I'm marking</strike> Amal's answer <strike>as the correct one, since it</strike> did lead me to solving the problem.  However, I wanted to add an answer of my own with a little more detail about the URL tokens, and how to use them.

I had previously run across this MSDN page on [URLs and Tokens in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms431831(v=office.15).aspx). In it, I saw that there is a token `~sitecollection` that can be used at the beginning of a URL, so I tried this:

```
<link href="~sitecollection/Style Library/custom/css/custom_v2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~sitecollection/Style Library/custom/img/logo3.png" runat="server" />
```

That didn't work.  Some kind of URL replacement was happening, but it was definitely not what I expected, and it was an invalid URL so the resources weren't getting loaded.

What they **don't** tell you on that page is the correct syntax for using the token, and that is this:

`<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Path/To/Resource %>`

Once I learned that was how to actually use the tokens, I implemented this:

```
<link href="<% $SPUrl: ~sitecollection/Style Library/custom/css/custom_v2.css%>" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<asp:Image ImageUrl='<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/custom/img/logo3.png %>' runat="server" />
```

Which is working great.  Interestingly, for script links, you have to wrap the token in an ASP literal control, so a script link using this method looks like this:

```
<script src='<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/custom/js/libs/jquery-2.1.1.min.js %>" />' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

So, I hope that helps anyone trying to figure out how to use the URL replacement tokens.

Comment: Dylan Cristy: You can mark yours as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

For CSS you can use

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:-sitecollection/Style Library/custom/css/custom_v2.css" %>" runat="server"/>
```

For Site Logo you can use

```
<SharePoint:SiteLogoImage LogoImageUrl="/Style Library/AdventureWorks/logo.png" AlternateText="Back to Home" ToolTip="Back to Home" runat="server"/>
```

Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg430141(v=office.14).aspx from more on branding